# Testing Services in PHP (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: php, function, testing, zend-framework, methods

I would like to know how to test a specific method I wrote in Utils.php and in example MynameService.php 
Is it possible ? 
Sorry if it's a stupid question I'm new in PHP and Frameworks.
Thanks for Answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common solution for this is "Xdebug". Maybe you can use it in your environment and in your IDE.

Maybe you find here something what you can use for your requirements: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php